# Change font of one character in a text box, using script

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

In Unity, is there a way to change the font of one character in a text box by using scripts? Ideally, I'd like to accomplish the following:

- Randomly select one character in a string of letters (a single text
  box; for example, a text box that says "Hello World").
- Randomly choose one of five fonts. Change the selected character to this chosen
  font.
- Accomplish this using scripts so that each time the player
  views the screen, they see the same text -- but a different letter is
  a different font each time.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish that? Selecting a random char from a string should be quite trivial .. however I don't think there is any built-in component that allows for different fonts on the same text. You could however simply split up your text into multiple text/text mesh pro components and pick one of them randomly and change the font of that one

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found that interesting ! It seems that with Text Mesh Pro you can use rich text tags like `<font="fontAsset">char</font>` but you have to make sure your font asset is loaded at runtime. It seems you should tell TMP where to search for the font in your setting.

From there, you can generate those tags at runtime around your character and voilà !

For more [informations](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#font)

Comment: Oh! That may be what I've been missing. I'm using Text Mesh Pro, but wasn't aware that the font asset should be loaded at runtime. I'll try this fix and report back with the results.